# query with multiple rows and join

Tags: plsql

I have two tables like these:

```
active
orderno status  state name
204     N       0   DANDO A SIN_CONDICION
190     N       L   JOB_AGENTE_SLEEP_200M
203     N       0   SIN_CONDICION
206     N       C   EJEMPLO_2
182     N       L   JOB_AGENTE
195     Y       8   BIENHECHO
186     N       L   JOB_AGENTE_SLEEP_20M
189     N       L   JOB_AGENTE_SLEEP_5S
205     Y       8   EJEMPLO_1
184     N       L   SSL_AGENTE920
183     N       L   LIFECONTROLM_JOB1_920
191     N       L   MFTAGENTEPRIMERO
187     N       L   SSL_AGENTE931
198     N       B   PTE_HORA_Y_CONDICION
194     N       L   MFTAGENTESECUNDARIO
201     N       B   COND2
197     N       B   PTE_HORA
192     N       L   931a920
185     N       L   LS_AGENTE920_OTRA_EJECUCION
188     N       L   AGENTE921
200     Y       8   COND1
196     Y       8   BIENHECHO2
193     N       C   SIN_CONDICION
202     Y       8   DANDO A SIN_CONDICION
199     Y       8   SIN_CONDICION
```

```
cmr
cond                            orderno rowtype date    op  
SIN_CONDICION                   193     I       1107    A   
COND1-TO-SIN_CONDICION          193     I       1107    A         
COND2-TO-SIN_CONDICION          193     I       1107    A   
COND1-TO-SIN_CONDICION          193     O       1107    -         
COND2-TO-SIN_CONDICION          193     O       1107    -         
BIENHECHO-TO-BIENHECHO2         195     O       1107    +         
BIENHECHO-TO-BIENHECHO2         196     I       1107    A     
BIENHECHO-TO-BIENHECHO2         196     O       1107    -         
PTE_HORA_Y_CONDICION            198     I       1107    A         
SIN_CONDICION                   199     I       1107    A         
SIN_CONDICION                   199     O       1107    -     
COND1-TO-PTE_HORA_Y_CONDICION   200     O       1107    +         
COND1-TO-SIN_CONDICION          200     O       1107    +         
COND2-TO-SIN_CONDICION          201     O       1107    +     
SIN_CONDICION                   202     O       1107    +         
SIN_CONDICION                   203     I       1107    A         
SIN_CONDICION2                  203     I       1107    A     
SIN_CONDICION2                  203     O       1107    -     
SIN_CONDICION                   204     O       1107    +         
EJEMPLO_1-TO-EJEMPLO_2          205     O       1107    +         
EJEMPLO_1-TO-EJEMPLO_2          206     I       1107    A         
CONDICION3                      206     I       1107    A         
EJEMPLO_1-TO-EJEMPLO_2          206     O       1107    -
```

I need these premises:
select only lines that have:
Row with name rowtype:I and op:A
Don't exists another row with same name, same date and rowtype:O and op:+

Then get the orderno of the row  and get name from the other table active.

I'm trying to put an example:

```
CONDICION3 have row rowtype:I and op:A with date 1107.
           don't have rowtype:O and op:+ with date 1107
```

**CONDICION3 meets requirementes, I search oderno in active table and it says me the name i'ts EJEMPLO_2**

```
EJEMPLO_1-TO-EJEMPLO_2 have row I-A with date 1107
                       have row O-+ with date 1107
```

**Nothing happens**

Could you help me please?
Thanks

Comment: Could share what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Not Exists query to exclude rows:

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e   d a ta :
    active (ORDERNO, STATUS, A_STATE, A_NAME) AS
        (   Select 204,     'N',     '0',   'DANDO A SIN_CONDICION' From Dual Union All
            Select 190,     'N',     'L',   'JOB_AGENTE_SLEEP_200M' From Dual Union All
            Select 203,     'N',     '0',   'SIN_CONDICION'         From Dual Union All
            Select 206,     'N',     'C',   'EJEMPLO_2'             From Dual Union All
            Select 182,     'N',     'L',   'JOB_AGENTE'            From Dual Union All
            Select 195,     'Y',     '8',   'BIENHECHO'             From Dual Union All
            Select 186,     'N',     'L',   'JOB_AGENTE_SLEEP_20M'  From Dual Union All
            Select 189,     'N',     'L',   'JOB_AGENTE_SLEEP_5S'   From Dual Union All
            Select 205,     'Y',     '8',   'EJEMPLO_1'             From Dual Union All
            Select 184,     'N',     'L',   'SSL_AGENTE920'         From Dual Union All
            Select 183,     'N',     'L',   'LIFECONTROLM_JOB1_920' From Dual Union All
            Select 191,     'N',     'L',   'MFTAGENTEPRIMERO'      From Dual Union All
            Select 187,     'N',     'L',   'SSL_AGENTE931'         From Dual Union All
            Select 198,     'N',     'B',   'PTE_HORA_Y_CONDICION'  From Dual Union All
            Select 194,     'N',     'L',   'MFTAGENTESECUNDARIO'   From Dual Union All
            Select 201,     'N',     'B',   'COND2'                 From Dual Union All
            Select 197,     'N',     'B',   'PTE_HORA'              From Dual Union All
            Select 192,     'N',     'L',   '931a920'               From Dual Union All
            Select 185,     'N',     'L',   'LS_AGENTE920_OTRA_EJECUCION' From Dual Union All
            Select 188,     'N',     'L',   'AGENTE921'             From Dual Union All
            Select 200,     'Y',     '8',   'COND1'                 From Dual Union All
            Select 196,     'Y',     '8',   'BIENHECHO2'            From Dual Union All
            Select 193,     'N',     'C',   'SIN_CONDICION'         From Dual Union All
            Select 202,     'Y',     '8',   'DANDO A SIN_CONDICION' From Dual Union All
            Select 199,     'Y',     '8',   'SIN_CONDICION'         From Dual 
        ), 
    cmr (COND, ORDERNO, A_ROWTYPE, A_DATE, OP) AS 
        (   Select 'SIN_CONDICION',                   193,     'I',       '1107',    'A' From Dual Union ALl   
            Select 'COND1-TO-SIN_CONDICION',          193,     'I',       '1107',    'A' From Dual Union ALl         
            Select 'COND2-TO-SIN_CONDICION',          193,     'I',       '1107',    'A' From Dual Union ALl
            Select 'COND1-TO-SIN_CONDICION',          193,     'O',       '1107',    '-' From Dual Union ALl
            Select 'COND2-TO-SIN_CONDICION',          193,     'O',       '1107',    '-' From Dual Union ALl         
            Select 'BIENHECHO-TO-BIENHECHO2',         195,     'O',       '1107',    '+' From Dual Union ALl         
            Select 'BIENHECHO-TO-BIENHECHO2',         196,     'I',       '1107',    'A' From Dual Union ALl     
            Select 'BIENHECHO-TO-BIENHECHO2',         196,     'O',       '1107',    '-' From Dual Union ALl         
            Select 'PTE_HORA_Y_CONDICION',            198,     'I',       '1107',    'A' From Dual Union ALl         
            Select 'SIN_CONDICION',                   199,     'I',       '1107',    'A' From Dual Union ALl         
            Select 'SIN_CONDICION',                   199,     'O',       '1107',    '-' From Dual Union ALl     
            Select 'COND1-TO-PTE_HORA_Y_CONDICION',   200,     'O',       '1107',    '+' From Dual Union ALl         
            Select 'COND1-TO-SIN_CONDICION',          200,     'O',       '1107',    '+' From Dual Union ALl         
            Select 'COND2-TO-SIN_CONDICION',          201,     'O',       '1107',    '+' From Dual Union ALl     
            Select 'SIN_CONDICION',                   202,     'O',       '1107',    '+' From Dual Union ALl         
            Select 'SIN_CONDICION',                   203,     'I',       '1107',    'A' From Dual Union ALl         
            Select 'SIN_CONDICION2',                  203,     'I',       '1107',    'A' From Dual Union ALl     
            Select 'SIN_CONDICION2',                  203,     'O',       '1107',    '-' From Dual Union ALl     
            Select 'SIN_CONDICION',                   204,     'O',       '1107',    '+' From Dual Union ALl         
            Select 'EJEMPLO_1-TO-EJEMPLO_2',          205,     'O',       '1107',    '+' From Dual Union ALl         
            Select 'EJEMPLO_1-TO-EJEMPLO_2',          206,     'I',       '1107',    'A' From Dual Union ALl         
            Select 'CONDICION3',                      206,     'I',       '1107',    'A' From Dual Union ALl         
            Select 'EJEMPLO_1-TO-EJEMPLO_2',          206,     'O',       '1107',    '-' From Dual  
        )
```

Below is the code that takes from cmr all rows with A_ROWTYPE = 'I' And OP = 'A' if there are no rows, for same ORDERNO and A_DATE, having A_ROWTYPE = 'O' And OP = '+'. Not sure if that's what you need but (if I missunderstood something) you can adjust the conditions the way you need them to be:

```sql
--  M a i n   S Q L :
Select      a.A_NAME, 
            c.COND, c.ORDERNO, c.A_ROWTYPE, c.A_DATE, c.OP
From        cmr c
Left Join   active a ON(a.ORDERNO = c.ORDERNO)
Where       c.A_ROWTYPE = 'I' And
            c.OP = 'A' And 
            Not Exists  ( Select 1 
                          From  cmr 
                          Where ORDERNO = c.ORDERNO And 
                                A_DATE = c.A_DATE And
                                A_ROWTYPE = 'O' And
                                OP = '+'
                        )
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
A_NAME                      COND                             ORDERNO A_ROWTYPE A_DATE OP
--------------------------- ----------------------------- ---------- --------- ------ --
SIN_CONDICION               SIN_CONDICION                        203 I         1107   A
SIN_CONDICION               SIN_CONDICION2                       203 I         1107   A
EJEMPLO_2                   EJEMPLO_1-TO-EJEMPLO_2               206 I         1107   A
EJEMPLO_2                   CONDICION3                           206 I         1107   A
PTE_HORA_Y_CONDICION        PTE_HORA_Y_CONDICION                 198 I         1107   A
BIENHECHO2                  BIENHECHO-TO-BIENHECHO2              196 I         1107   A
SIN_CONDICION               SIN_CONDICION                        193 I         1107   A
SIN_CONDICION               COND1-TO-SIN_CONDICION               193 I         1107   A
SIN_CONDICION               COND2-TO-SIN_CONDICION               193 I         1107   A
SIN_CONDICION               SIN_CONDICION                        199 I         1107   A   */
```

Not sure, but it might be that for Not Exists query, it could be that you want COND as condition instead of ORDERNO. In that case the code would be:

```sql
--  M i n   S Q L :
Select      a.A_NAME, 
            c.COND, c.ORDERNO, c.A_ROWTYPE, c.A_DATE, c.OP
From        cmr c
Left Join   active a ON(a.ORDERNO = c.ORDERNO)
Where       c.A_ROWTYPE = 'I' And
            c.OP = 'A' And 
            Not Exists  ( Select 1 
                          From  cmr 
                          Where COND = c.COND And 
                                A_DATE = c.A_DATE And
                                A_ROWTYPE = 'O' And
                                OP = '+'
                        )
/*    R e s u l t :
A_NAME                      COND                             ORDERNO A_ROWTYPE A_DATE OP
--------------------------- ----------------------------- ---------- --------- ------ --
SIN_CONDICION               SIN_CONDICION2                       203 I         1107   A
EJEMPLO_2                   CONDICION3                           206 I         1107   A
PTE_HORA_Y_CONDICION        PTE_HORA_Y_CONDICION                 198 I         1107   A   */
```

Without ORDERNO or COND as conditions in Not Exists query:

```sql
--  M i n   S Q L :
Select      a.A_NAME, 
            c.COND, c.ORDERNO, c.A_ROWTYPE, c.A_DATE, c.OP
From        cmr c
Left Join   active a ON(a.ORDERNO = c.ORDERNO)
Where       c.A_ROWTYPE = 'I' And
            c.OP = 'A' And 
            Not Exists  ( Select 1 
                          From  cmr 
                          Where A_DATE = c.A_DATE And
                                A_ROWTYPE = 'O' And
                                OP = '+'
                        )
--  R e s u l t :
--  No  rows selected
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  COND- SIN_CONDICION shouldn't appears for example. The condition is that there are now rows with same DATE and having A_ROWTYPE = 'O' And OP = '+. I shouldn't compare orderno.

Comment: @Miguel7799 If ORDERNO is not a condition then just comment out the -- ORDERNO = c.ORDERNO line (After Where) but in that case there are no rows selected.You should either provide the expected result or, at  least, clarify your conditions in an explicite way. Conditions described in the question are in some aspects contradictory.

Comment: @Miguel7799 Another important thing - what is the join between the tables - is it ORDERNO or maybe A_NAME and COND OR part of it contained in another ???

Comment: Correct, I comment orderno and the jobin must be with orderno. Don't have others common columns

Comment: @Miguel7799 there are 2 more options added to the answer. Check them out or adjust to your actual context. I realy can't be sure what it should  look like.